# How to find conflicting composer package?

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm trying to update PHPUnit version on a project I'm going to create based on [Cilex](https://github.com/Cilex/Cilex). It has PHPUnit version `~3.7`. When I run `composer require phpunit/phpunit:~6 --dev` it prints out:

```
Problem 1
    - Can only install one of: phpunit/php-code-coverage[5.2.2, 1.2.18].
    - Can only install one of: phpunit/php-code-coverage[5.2.2, 1.2.18].
    - Can only install one of: phpunit/php-code-coverage[5.2.2, 1.2.18].
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.3.0 requires phpunit/php-code-coverage ^5.2.2 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[5.2.2].
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit ^6.3 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[6.3.0].
    - Installation request for phpunit/php-code-coverage (locked at 1.2.18) -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[1.2.18].
```

However it won't say which package is the offending one. The composer file is [this one](https://github.com/Cilex/Cilex/blob/develop/composer.json).

**PS:**
Also, I ran `composer require php:~7.1` just in case, and it worked, but updating PHPUnit after that still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Require package with `--update-with-dependencies`

Run

```
$ composer require phpunit/phpunit:^6.0.0 --update-with-dependencies
```

to update `phpunit/phpunit` while updating its dependencies at the same time.

See https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require:

> - **--update-with-dependencies**: Also update dependencies of the newly required packages.

#### List reasons

If this doesn't help, run

```
$ composer why-not phpunit/phpunit:^6.0.0
```

to list reasons why the package could not be installed.